# Mysql join two table and set group in all tables

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have two table in my database, customers and shops.

I want to get all customers and clarify that a customer is a debtor or not.

For this job I want to create a mysql query that get the customers and join the shop table. 
I want to set condition for if `shops.price_status` column = 1 come and sum price value in shops table.

Otherwise the value of those row for price column in shop table equal to 0.

My shop table structure with some example data

```sql
id   customer_id   product_id  price    price_status
1    81            12          300      1
2    81            12          100      0
3    81            15          200      1
4    90            10          600      0
5    90            15          50       1
6    63            16          10       0
```

And my customer table (You should know some customers don't shop any product by I want to see them)

```sql
id   name
63.  Eva
64.  Nva
81.  Ali
82.  Bill
90.  Mosh
```

An I want to get this result

```sql
Eva.   0.  // Because price status = 0
Nva.   0.  
Ali.   500 // because have two row that prices status = 1
Bill.  0. 
Mosh.  50. // Because have one row with price status = 1
```

Comment: o_O `SUM(price*price_status)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can do with `[MySQL if][1]`

```
SELECT
    c.`name`,sum(if(s.price_status=1,s.price,0)) as price
FROM
customer AS c

    LEFT JOIN
    shops AS s
    ON 
        c.id=s.customer_id 
GROUP BY
    c.id;
```

if you accept null value in `price` you can use

```
SELECT
    c.`name`,sum(s.price_status*s.price) as price
FROM
customer AS c

    LEFT JOIN
    shops AS s
    ON 
        c.id=s.customer_id 
GROUP BY
    c.id;
```